# Failed to run expo android apk build

Tags: android, build, apk, expo

I've made a build with `expo build:android`, installed it on test device, after run it I had an error.

While it runs with expo in production mode it's ok, it fails only after I made a build.
Have no idea what's wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try below steps

- Update expo
- Restart server
- Create a build for Android

Also, make sure that you added package name in `app.json` like

```
"android": {
      "package": "com.companyname.appname",
      "versionCode": 1
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. I forget to add package name.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I used wrong command for build.
I should use `expo build:android -t apk --release-chanel prod` cause of `expo-constants` I have in my application